# qt infix to prefix application

Tags: c++, qt

i wrote a infix to prefix code on codes blocks and it works fine and can handle the brackets .. 
i moved to qt recently so i i just copied the code the code to qt . and changed String to QString. So far it works for cases and do not work with brackets, 
here the code function written in codes blocks ( which work's 100%)

```
    string InfixToPrefix(string infix)
{
    stackk s;
    char ValueToPushOrPop;
    s.init(20);
    string postfix = "";
    for(int i = 0; i< infix.length(); i++)
    {
        if(IsOperand(infix[i]))
            postfix +=infix[i];

        else if(IsOperator(infix[i]))
        {
            if(!s.isempty())
            {
                while((!s.isempty())&&(s.topp()!='(') && (HasHighPrecedence(s.topp(),infix[i]))) // those line responsible for checking precedence
                {
                    postfix+=s.topp();
                    s.pop(&ValueToPushOrPop);
                }
            }
            s.push(infix[i]);
        }
        else if(infix[i]==')')
        {
            while(!s.isempty()&&s.topp()!='(')
            {
                postfix+=s.topp();
                s.pop(&ValueToPushOrPop);
            }
            s.pop(&ValueToPushOrPop);
        }
        else if(infix[i]=='(')
            s.push(infix[i]);
    }
    while(!s.isempty())
    {
        s.pop(&ValueToPushOrPop);
        if(ValueToPushOrPop!='(')
            postfix+=ValueToPushOrPop;
    }
    return postfix;
    postfix.clear();
}
```

the qt function

```
 QString InfixToPrefix(QString infix)
{
    QStack<char> s;
    QString postfix = "";
    for(int i = 0; i< infix.length(); i++)
    {
        if(IsOperand(QString(infix).toStdString()[i]))
                postfix +=QString(infix).toStdString()[i];
        else if(IsOperator(QString(infix).toStdString()[i]))
        {
            if(!s.isEmpty())
            {
                while((!s.isEmpty())&&(s.top()!='(') && (HasHighPrecedence(s.top(),QString(infix).toStdString()[i]))) // those line responsible for checking precedence
                {
                    postfix.append(s.top());
                    s.pop();
                }
            }
            s.push(QString(infix).toStdString()[i]);
        }
        else if(QString(infix).toStdString()[i]==')')
        {
            while(!s.isEmpty()&&s.top()!='(')
            {
                postfix.append(s.top());
                s.pop();
            }
            s.pop();
        }
        else if(QString(infix).toStdString()[i]=='(')
        {
            s.push(QString(infix).toStdString()[i]);
           }
    }
    while(!s.isEmpty())
    {
        if(s.top()!='(')
        postfix.append(s.top());
        s.pop();
    }
    return postfix;
```

click there ro view the image

[he didn't handle the brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb9qZ.png)

.. wating for reponse , thanks in advance .

Comment: And what exactly is your question? And why is this question/the problem related to qt?

Comment: what is the diff between string and qstring ,, why my programe failes when i changed from string to qstring .  why it cant handle the brackets ? .

Comment: Besides: `QString(infix).toStdString()[i]`is quite strange, you can write `Infix.toStdString()[i]` or even better convert `infix.toStdString()` only once and then work on the `std::string`.

Comment: i used it becouse . i get this error when using infix[i] " "error: C2664: 'IsOperand' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QCharRef' to 'char'
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called ""

Comment: Sorry, I just recognized the reason my self and changed my comment.

Comment: okay , i just convert it to string, and when finished convert it back to qstring . but same issue no handling for brackets :)

Comment: Can you please replace the image by text: 1. your input, 2. the output of string-variant and 3. the output of the QString variant!?

Comment: sir sorry for wasting your time . i discovered the problem i called the function twice . but thanks any way . i learned how to convert from Qstring to string :) ^^